# Change Bundle ID iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I set up my application in iTunes Connect. It has not been submitted yet (Ever). Later, I saw that my bundle identifier was not matching with the one in my Xcode project and iTunes Connect. I cannot change the bundle identifier in Xcode because it is faded out.

So I tried changing it in iTunes Connect by making a brand new app id with the correct bundle identifier. I go into my application within iTunes Connect and selecting a brand new bundle identifier from the drop down list but I do not see the one I just recently made.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can change the bundle identifier within iTunes Connect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me, but I was able to see the new bundle id after logging out of iTunes connect and refreshing the page. I believe this is a problem with the new developer portal... It took 5 minutes once then refreshed and it appeared in the dropdown list.

Hope this helps, good luck!

UPDATE: Make sure you press the SUBMIT button after creating the new Bundle ID in the developer portal then press DONE... the log back into iTunes connect and it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably less effort to change the bundle ID in your Xcode project instead of registering a new one with iTunes Connect.

You may change the bundle identifier by editing the Info.plist file.